# Why is HTML 5 validation triggered if I don't have a HTML 5 doctype?

Tags: html, dojo, validation

I've run into this a few times now and it's getting annoying.  In Dojo there is a required attribute to trigger form validation.  HTML 5 now also uses this same attribute.  The problem comes in because HTML5 doesns't care what the value of required= is required="anything" means it's required.

So on my form elements if I have required="false" to indicate to dojo I do not want this validated. In some instances on Chrome and Firefox HTML 5 validation is running on that input field.

I've tried the HTML 5 novalidate attribute but it seems if required attribute is there it ignores it.

I guess I should ask a question. How do I disable HTML5 validation altogether?  or put another way Why is HTML 5 validation running if I'm not specifying an HTML 5 doc type.

Thanks

Here is full sample of the issue. Open this in Firefox or Chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");

    dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
      dojo.parser.parse();
    });
  </script>
  <form novalidate="novalidate" dojoType="dijit.form.Form">
  <select required="false" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">
    <option value="" >Please Choose A Category...</option>
    <option value="one" >One</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your second question...

> Why is HTML 5 validation running if
>   I'm not specifying an HTML 5 doc type?

The "HTML5 DOCTYPE" is not a method of identifying "HTML5 documents". It's just the shortest DOCTYPE that ensures that standards mode is triggered in the browsers (and that's why it was chosen in the HTML5 spec).

Also, there is no such thing as an "HTML5 document". The document is either written in HTML or not. You can say that your HTML document contains some features that are defined for the first time in the HTML5 spec (we can call them "HTML5 features").

Browsers do *not* apply different rules to HTML documents that have the "HTML5 doctype".

Comment: This correctly answers the main question, thank you.  The secondary issue seems to be with Dojo so I filed a bug there. [Dojo Bug Report](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/13237)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable validation by putting `novalidate` inside your `form` tag, or `formnovalidate` inside any individual `input`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  My form tag is below. I will see if I can post a small example.`<form novalidate="novalidate" method="POST" name="form_new" id="form_new" dojoType="dijit.form.Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: See sample HTML in question.  novalidate does not work in the case.  This might be a Dojo bug

Comment: @Dustin Dojo is the cause of your issue. If you remove `dojoType="dijit.form.Form"`, I'll work. Consider filing a [bug report](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/)...